# How can I get json objects without the object number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I have a simple json object that spits out 4 items that have completely different properties inside each one. I have got the json being displayed with the 4 objects that are called `meta.work_content` like so:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

I can open these in console and see the objects like so:

```
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
```

I can go further into each one etc. In my javascript I have got a simple ajax request getting the items with the following setup:

```
var getPosts = function() {

        $.ajax({
          url: '/wp-json/posts?type=case-studies',
          data: {
            filter: {
            'name': _last
            }
          },
          success: function ( dataS ) {
            //List some global variables here to fetch post data
            // We use base as our global object to find resources we need
            var base = dataS[0];
            console.log(base);
            var postContent = base.content;
            var postTitle = base.title;
            // Main Image ACF object
            var featuredImage = base.meta.main_image;
            // Gallery ACF object
            var nodes = base.meta.work_content;
            // output ACF objects
            console.log(nodes);
          },
          cache: false
        });

    };
```

Now here comes the tricky part, I want to access each `meta.work_content` object but without using this to do it `base.meta.work_content[0], base.meta.work_content[1]` etc as each items order will change and so these numbers will be irrelevant.

The items need to be access based on their object name not the `[0],[1],[2]` as thats not going to work.

Cheers

Comment: Use a key to define each object instead of placing all your different object in one array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an object.
2. Loop over the array
3. Get the name of each member of the array
4. Copy each member into the object using a property name that is the same as the name you just got

Then just use the object instead of the array.

You might want to think about what should happen if two objects have the same name (if that is possible).

Comment: Hi Quentin, do you have an example of where this might have been done before? Is the answer above by Mivaweb what you mean?

Comment: @Mdunbavan — Each of these steps is really, really basic JS. Which one is giving you problems?

Comment: I know that but it's more of how it fits into the context of what I am doing above. I have already got the object `nodes` if I loop over the array of `nodes` will this affect the order they come in? Then last bit copying the object, will that make things more complex than it needs to be?

Comment: If you want to access them by name instead of index then of course it will effect the order — you're not accessing them by order any more — but you'll still have access to the original array if you want to get them in order. If accessing them by name will make things simpler for you, then copying them into an object so you can access them by name won't make things more complex.

Comment: I think I will try and have a go at this. The other option is to keep the index and just use an if statement to look for the item names inside each one and do something for each one that way? The other thing I forgot to mention is that there will be multiple items with the same names inside the object

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var objects = {
        // Key `object1` which contains sertain properties
        object1: { name: "Name" },

        // Key `object2` which contains sertain properties
        object2: { firstname: "Fname" }
    };

    alert(objects.object1.name); // eg Name
    alert(objects.object2.firstname); // eg Fname

    // Check if object exists
    if(objects.object1)
    {
        // Do something with the properties of object1
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Using your example:

```
success: function ( dataS ) {
    var nodes = dataS; // Eg nodes is like objects in my example above

    // Object 1
    var base = nodes.object1; // Eg object1 is the name of your object
    var postContent = base.content;
    var postTitle = base.title;
    var featuredImage = base.meta.main_image;
},
```

Comment: How could this work with the `nodes` object and still retain the order they come in at?

Comment: The order of your ajax result is done by your backend. Also this doesn't matter if `object1` is first or `object2` is first, you access objects based on their name

Comment: Does `objects` reference the same as how I am using `nodes` in my code above? What i am trying to say is could I do `var nodes={object1: { name: "Name" } etc}` and get the same result?

Comment: View my update above, It represents short the way you have to do it with your example

Comment: bearing in mind this is a complex nested set of json too I think this will not work. Nodes is the object with multiple items inside it not `dataS`